# The meaning of a statement

Tags: meaning

In a journal, the following statement is a condition for submitting a paper. Does this statement mean that I must pay in order to publish my paper? If not, what is its meaning?

> If desired, 25 free offprints of the article will be sent to the corresponding author. Additional offprints can be ordered when sending the proof corrections. The article can also be published in Open Access (that is, with the final print file also freely downloadable) upon paying a fee of 300 euros. The decision should be communicated at the proof stage; the appropriate invoice will then be sent to the author.

If it is possible, please clarify the meaning.

Comment: Note to reviewers: I think the *proofreading* exception applies because there is a specific source of concern is identified - namely, whether it means the OP must pay under certain conditions. Voting to leave open.

Answer (score 3):

1. The corresponding author will get 25 copies of the printed version of the paper. (Later you can order more, if you want.)
2. If you want your paper to be Open Access (freely downloadable for anyone) you have to pay a fee. Otherwise the future readers of your paper will pay for it. Simply saying, someone has to pay to the publisher, if not the readers, then you must.